# Adhoc modify an object instances methods and properties in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, scope, this

I want to be able to add/modify properties and methods of an object without having to constantly refer to the objects variable. For example:

```
var myObj = new MyClass();

myObj.function() {
    this.str = 'String';
    this.fn =  function() {
        // Function here...
    }
}
```

As opposed to:

```
var myObj = new MyClass();

myObj.str = 'String';
myObj.fn = function() {
    // Function here...
}
```

I am aware that the first example does not work because you can't call an anonymous function in this way. However is there a way to be able to do something like this so that blocks of code can be written in the objects variable scope. I want to be able use 'this' instead of the variable name.

Please note that I only want to do this for a single instance of an object... I do not need to modify the class or create a new one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
(function () {
    this.str = 'String';
    this.fn = function () { /* ... */ };
}).call(myObj);
```

Or, even simpler:

```
(function (x) {
    x.str = 'String';
    x.fn = function () { /* ... */ };
})(myObj);
```

But I have to ask why you want to do this.  Is `myObj` some ridiculously long name?

Comment: Yeah it is quite long... And I am also adding quite a few more properties and methods. I don't feel so much repetition of the variable name follows good OOP practices.

Answer (score 3):

```
function decorateInstance() {
    this.foo = "42";

    this.go = function() {
        return this.foo;
    }
}

var o = {};
decorateInstance.call(o);
console.log(o.foo);
console.log(o.go());​
```

Comment: Also a great solution. Thanks Peter!